# Which file to edit to change text color in cakephp

Tags: css, cakephp, text, colors

I am using the Cakephp framework and I need help changing the text color of my dialog boxes.

The text and headers are white in the dialog box, but if I disable the dialog box and go directly to the action's view in the browser the text is color is fine.  I was wondering if this is something that needs to be edited in layout.css or text.css.

I have no idea what I am doing when it comes to css files.
I'm hoping its just a small change of one line in a css file but I don't know which one.

If this question is too ambiguous or unsolvable, I will delete it.

Thanks for the help

Edit ------------------------
I found out that this is the codefrom layout.css.

```
tbody td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-top: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}
```

The white colored text is in a table cell,

what should I change to make it black?

Comment: add this attribute : color:#000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your css class or id form /app/webroot/css/styles.css. and check it by firebug. It is applying or not?..

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in `/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css`.

You'll want to add the property `color` to your dialogue box css. (e.g. `color: black;`)

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug on Firefox or just right click and chose Inspect Element on Chrome to see in which CSS file properties are defined.